# Accessing an Instance of a Variable form Another Class

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a Java project where, in one class, an array is initialized, like so.

```
public class pixel {
    public boolean[] pixelAvailability = new boolean[100];
}
```

In my main class, a method of another class I've created is run. The code for that method is as shown below.

```
public void walls() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        // This is the part I need help with!
    }
}
```

The intended use of this method is to change the value of some entries in the pixelAvailability array. In the space where the comment is, there's supposed to be a line that accesses the array, and will change the index of the array that has the same value of 'i' to true. However, I'm not sure what'd I'd write there, in order to change the value of the pixelAvailability array that exists in an instance of the pixel class that wasn't created in the "walls" class itself. The main class simply creates two instances of both classes, and is written like so.

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pixel pixelObj = new pixel();
        wall wallObj = new wall();

        walls();
    }
}
```

While I could write the code for the "walls" method in the main method, it'd take up a lot of space and make it a bit messier, and seems unnecessary.

There is a fourth class unrelated to this particular problem, but will also have the issue of accessing the values in the pixelAvailability array. Any helps or tips are much appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to create some dependencies between your classes - e.g. have `walls` accept a `pixel` instance in its constructor

Comment: Note: since `i = 1` the `i >= 10` is always false. Most likely you meant `i <= 10`

Comment: Unless there is a reason to use `pixels` elsewhere I would make it a field of the `walls` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the Pixel object as an argument, first change your wall method to receive a Pixel as param

```
public void walls(Pixel pixel) {
    for (int i = 1; i >= 10; i++) {
        // here you can do whatever you want like pixel.pixelAvailability[i] = false;

    }
}
```

then in your main, you pass the Pixel as a param

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pixel pixelObj = new pixel();
        wall wallObj = new wall();

        walls(pixelObj); //here you do the magic
    }
}
```

Basically, you are changing your walls method to accept a Pixel instance as param. So you can access it inside your method.

Now, whenever you call the walls method you can pass any Pixel object to it.

For more info, you can check this link

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I was having trouble with. Could you explain a bit, though, what the first line in the first example is doing? The "(Pixel pixel)" part?

Comment: I've updated the answer with some more details, and a link for further information.